# Anime with a boy who shatters everything he touches

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this [reel on Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/reel/Cv4UWmqgFF0/) but I can't find the name of the anime.

[image: Four maids.]
[image: Hands with black marks on the back in cuffs. Chinese text: 我一生下来就带有触碰物体会破坏掉得因果诅咒.]

Comments are not enabled and even translating the Arabic text did not give me the name of the anime.

[image: "He was born with a strange power.. that makes anything he touches shatter, so all his thoughts"]

Does anyone know the name of this anime?

Comment: The Chinese text in the second image is "我一生下来就带有触碰物体会破坏掉得因果诅咒", which Google Translate gives me as "I was born with a curse of karma that touches objects and destroys them".

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yeah but even that doesn't give any results

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Duke_of_Death_and_His_Maid has some similarities, but doesn't quite match.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [Chaos Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_Dragon).  Found thanks to [some Japanese site](http://blog.livedoor.jp/aya_g/archives/1036949719.html) with a matching image.

A [review](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/review/chaos-dragon/episodes-6-7/.91714):

> Mostly these episodes are about Sweallow, as his true motivation for joining the expedition is both introduced and destroyed inside of episode 7. Earlier episodes have established that Sweallow's ennui comes from his central skill: the ability to use any tool to its maximum potential at the cost of that tool's "life." I thought this Edward Scissorhands sort of cheese would have a tragic past lurking behind it, but I was not expecting this. Sweallow's sepia-toned backstory turns out to be the most middle-school-poetry-slam version of events you can imagine based on his forever-alone-tiny-violin superskill. **We are treated to scenes of baby Sweallow sitting on his four-poster bed in a regal D'Natia mansion with his hands locked in stocks, as a flurry of maids gasp in horror when every spoon he uses to eat his gruel explodes into pieces**.

Comment: Beat me to it. Curses!

Comment: @Valorum And I did this on mobile :p

Comment: I actually found it almost immediately using an image search, but when I looked at the first episode I couldn't see anything that matched, so I didn't post it as an answer

Comment: Huh. I too had had it pop up, but without anything that made me think it was viable. :-P